# For autoincrement fields: MAX(ID) vs TOP 1 ID ORDER BY ID DESC

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

I want to find the highest AutoIncremented value from a field. (its not being fetched after an insert where I can use `@@SCOPE_IDENTITY` etc)
Which of these two queries would run faster or gives better performance.
`Id` is the primary key and `autoincrement` field for `Table1`. And this is for Sql Server 2005.

```
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table1

SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Table1 ORDER BY Id DESC
```

**[Edit]**
Yes in this case `Id` is the field on which I have defined the clustered index.
If the index is `ID DESC` then what..
And yes it would be nice to know how the performance would be affected if 
1. Id is a clustered index + primary key.
2. Id is a clustered index and not primary key.
3. Id is a non clustered index ASC + primary key.
4. Id is a non clustered index ASC  and not primary key.
5. Id is a non clustered index DESC + primary key.
6. Id is a non clustered index DESC and not primary key.
7. Id is just `AutoIncrement`

Hope its not a tall order!

Comment: From the answers here, with the index there's no difference in performance. However I've found `MAX`/`MIN` has a couple of benefits. Firstly as noted below without an index `MAX` will be more performant, this also becomes significant when you have more complex joins in place. Secondly if there are NULLs then `SELECT MIN` returns a value but `SELECT TOP 1 ... ASC` returns `NULL`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory, they will use same plans and run almost same time.

In practice,

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Table1 ORDER BY Id DESC
```

will more probably use a `PRIMARY KEY INDEX`.

Also, this one is more extendable if you will decide to select some else column along with `id`.

An actual plan on `MAX()` says:

```
SELECT <- AGGREGATE <- TOP <- CLUSTERED INDEX SCAN
```

, while plan for `TOP 1` says:

```
SELECT <- TOP <- CLUSTERED INDEX SCAN
```

, i. e. `aggregate` is omitted.

Aggregate actually won't do anything here, as there is but one row.

*P. S.* As `@Mehrdad Afshari` and `@John Sansom` noted, on a non-indexed field `MAX` is slightly faster (of course not `20` times as optimizer says):

```
-- 18,874,368 rows

SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON
PRINT 'MAX'
SELECT MAX(id) FROM master
PRINT 'TOP 1'
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM master ORDER BY id DESC
PRINT 'MAX'
SELECT MAX(id) FROM master
PRINT 'TOP 1'
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM master ORDER BY id DESC
PRINT 'MAX'
SELECT MAX(id) FROM master
PRINT 'TOP 1'
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM master ORDER BY id DESC
PRINT 'MAX'
SELECT MAX(id) FROM master
PRINT 'TOP 1'
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM master ORDER BY id DESC
PRINT 'MAX'
SELECT MAX(id) FROM master
PRINT 'TOP 1'
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM master ORDER BY id DESC

Changed language setting to us_english.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
MAX

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 20 ms.

(строк обработано: 1)
Table 'master'. Scan count 3, logical reads 32655, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 447, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 5452 ms,  elapsed time = 2766 ms.
TOP 1

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(строк обработано: 1)
Table 'master'. Scan count 3, logical reads 32655, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 2, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 6813 ms,  elapsed time = 3449 ms.
MAX

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(строк обработано: 1)
Table 'master'. Scan count 3, logical reads 32655, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 44, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 5359 ms,  elapsed time = 2714 ms.
TOP 1

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(строк обработано: 1)
Table 'master'. Scan count 3, logical reads 32655, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 6766 ms,  elapsed time = 3379 ms.
MAX

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(строк обработано: 1)
Table 'master'. Scan count 3, logical reads 32655, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 5406 ms,  elapsed time = 2726 ms.
TOP 1

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(строк обработано: 1)
Table 'master'. Scan count 3, logical reads 32655, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 6780 ms,  elapsed time = 3415 ms.
MAX

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(строк обработано: 1)
Table 'master'. Scan count 3, logical reads 32655, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 85, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 5392 ms,  elapsed time = 2709 ms.
TOP 1

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(строк обработано: 1)
Table 'master'. Scan count 3, logical reads 32655, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 10, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 6766 ms,  elapsed time = 3387 ms.
MAX

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(строк обработано: 1)
Table 'master'. Scan count 3, logical reads 32655, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 5374 ms,  elapsed time = 2708 ms.
TOP 1

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

(строк обработано: 1)
Table 'master'. Scan count 3, logical reads 32655, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 6797 ms,  elapsed time = 3494 ms.
```

Comment: Query optimizer is deterministic. How come something will "more probably" use an index?

Comment: Optimizer's decisions depend on table statistics which depend on table data which are probabilistic. An optimizer MAY decide to sort the table instead of using and INDEX SCAN along with TOP.

Comment: I am late to the party, but any idea what is the memory efficiency of the two plans for an indexed field scenario? If we have the same query running huge number of times, whichever plan takes higher buffer will lose.

Answer (score 10):

Nobody mentioned IDENT_CURRENT('Table1') - blows them all away - of course it only works on identity columns, but that *was* the question...

Comment: Voted up, but not *always* applicable because `IDENT_CURRENT` isn't necessarily in scope. 
To be fastest and safest the transaction should be in a stored procedure and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Answer (score 9):

**If there is a clustered index there is virtually no difference in performance between the two queries.**

This is becuase both will perform a Clustered Index Scan that will bear 100% of the query cost.

Performing the two queries on a column that does not have an index results in 3 operators being used in both execution plans.

The Top clause uses the Sort operator and the Max function uses a Stream Aggregate operator.

When there is no index, the MAX() function provides better performance.

Proof of concept can be found and full walkthrough of a test scenario can be found here:

[Performance Comparison Top 1 Verses MAX() Function](https://www.johnsansom.com/performance-comparison-of-select-top-1-verses-max/)

Comment: he indexed case, the stream aggregate operator will have "Actual Rows = 1" which basically costs nothing. If you don't have an index, the execution plan for TOP 1 will have a "Top N" sort which will make it slower than the "Stream Aggregate" that MAX uses.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Indeed it does, full details will be added to my blog.

Comment: @John, use the permanent link to this question on  your blog http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590079/

Comment: It's a shame that there is no optimization about "top 1 ... order by pk desc", at least in SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3):

Just compare execution plans and you'll see (press `Ctrl+M` in Management Studio when editing a query). My wild guess will be that these queries are equally performant provided there is a (clustered) index on `Id` column.

However, this as a whole is a *very bad* idea.

Comment: Using additional queries to retrieve the ID of a newly added row is a very bad idea. Quite a lot of database operations may occur between these two requests.

Comment: @Anton please read the question carefully I have clearly stated that "(its not being fetched after an insert where I can use @@SCOPE_IDENTITY etc)"

Answer (score 2):

`MAX` is generally faster.

Both queries will use the index on the column if exists.

If no index exists on the column, the `TOP 1` query will use a `Top N Sort` operator to **sort** the table instead of **stream aggregation**, which makes it slower.

`MAX` also provides better readability.

*Side Note*: while `MAX` will use a stream aggregate operator in the execution plan in the indexed case, it doesn't have any specific cost as it's just processing a single row (`Actual Rows = 1`). You can compare queries by running them in a single batch and see the relative cost. In the indexed case, both queries will cost 50%. I tested the non-indexed case on a table with about 7000 rows and TOP will cost 65% in comparison to MAX that costs 35%.

Comment: TOP 1 will not sort the query. The question explicitly notes that ID is a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: And I think I explicitly mentioned "if no index exists on the column". Read more carefully.

Comment: An index always exists on a primary key.

Comment: Yes it does, but remember, SO is something more or less like wikipedia. It never hurts to answer more generally. I think I first answered the question with "Both queries will use the index on the column if exists." and after that clarified the general case to avoid pitfalls.

Comment: Maybe it's a communication fault from my side, but as I see your answer, is says that TOP 1 will always sort the table, even if it uses the index. That's not true.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to say that. I'll fix the wording to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested the two SQL statements you provided against a typical dataset:

```
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table1

SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Table1 ORDER BY Id DESC
```

And `SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Table1 ORDER BY Id DESC` is marginally faster because it has one fewer step in the execution plan. Here are the execution plans each query carries out:

**SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Table1**

Clustered Index Scan >> Top >> Stream Aggregate >> Select

**SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Table1 ORDER BY Id DESC**

Clustered Index Scan >> Top >> Select

Answer (score 1):

> Yes in this case Id is the field on
> which I have defined the clustered
> index. If the index is ID DESC then
> what.. And yes it would be nice to
> know how the performance would be
> affected if
>
> 1. Id is a clustered index + primary key.
> 2. Id is a clustered index and not primary key.
> 3. Id is a non clustered index ASC + primary key.
> 4. Id is a non clustered index ASC and not primary key.
> 5. Id is a non clustered index DESC + primary key.
> 6. Id is a non clustered index DESC and not primary key.
> 7. Id is just AutoIncrement

For Cases 1 and 2, both will perform a clustered index scan that returns a single record.  There is no IO difference between the two queries.

For Cases 3, 4, 5 and 6, both will perform an index scan that returns a single record.  There is no IO difference between the two queries.

For Case 7, both will perform a table scan.  There is no difference in the IO cost.

Summary:  Case 1-6 are made of win!  If you're in Case 7, then you've already lost from an IO standpoint.

You can measure IO by using SQL's Query analyzer.  Run this before your query.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```