# How to get difference between two rows for a column field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table like this:

```
rowInt  Value
2       23
3       45
17      10
9       0
....
```

The column rowInt values are integer but not in a sequence with same increament. I can use the following sql to list values by rowInt:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY rowInt;
```

This will list values by rowInt. How can get get the difference of Value between two rows with the result like this:

```
rowInt   Value Diff
2        23    22    --45-23
3        45    -35   --10-45
9        0     -45   --0-45
17       10    10    -- 10-0
....
```

The table is in SQL 2005 (Miscrosoft)

Comment: Is it intended that you have 10-45 in the second row? Where do you take a 10 from?

Comment: some of the calcs are not consistent...  row2's (45-23) is row3-row2, but row9's (0-45) is row9-row3, should it not be (10-0) which is row17-row9?

Comment: It seems you want to count the difference between the adjacent values in your original rowset (2, 3, 17, 9). Then I'll have to ask you: what is the column your ORIGINAL rowset is sorted on? Remember that there is no such thing as 'default ordering' in SQL.

Comment: Anyways, fix the question. (--10-45) is not right.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
SELECT
   [current].rowInt,
   [current].Value,
   ISNULL([next].Value, 0) - [current].Value
FROM
   sourceTable       AS [current]
LEFT JOIN
   sourceTable       AS [next]
      ON [next].rowInt = (SELECT MIN(rowInt) FROM sourceTable WHERE rowInt > [current].rowInt)
```

***EDIT:***

Thinking about it, using a subquery in the select (ala Quassnoi's answer) may be more efficient.  I would trial different versions, and look at the execution plans to see which would perform best on the size of data set that you have...

***EDIT2:***

I still see this garnering votes, though it's unlikely many people still use SQL Server 2005.

If you have access to Windowed Functions such as `LEAD()`, then use that instead...

```
SELECT
  RowInt,
  Value,
  LEAD(Value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY RowInt) - Value
FROM
  sourceTable
```

Comment: If he has an index on rowInt (which I think he does) then my query is more efficient. If he doesn't, then your one is (if it's possible to talk about efficiency in this case). Look here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590079/for-autoincrement-fields-maxid-vs-top-1-id-order-by-id-desc

Comment: I created a dummy table with 1 million randomly created records and found that both queries took the same time.  In fact the only difference in execution plans was the position of a SORT function (I sorted the final output)

Answer (score 28):

```
SELECT rowInt, Value,
       COALESCE(
       (
       SELECT TOP 1 Value
       FROM myTable mi
       WHERE mi.rowInt > m.rowInt
       ORDER BY
             rowInt
       ), 0) - Value AS diff
FROM  myTable m
ORDER BY
      rowInt
```

Answer (score 19):

SQL Server 2012 and up support [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) / [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) functions to access the previous or subsequent row. SQL Server 2005 does not support this (in SQL2005 you need a join or something else).

A SQL 2012 example on this data

```
/* Prepare */
select * into #tmp
from
(
    select 2  as rowint,      23 as Value
    union select 3,       45
    union select 17,      10
    union select 9,       0
) x


/* The SQL 2012 query */
select rowInt, Value, LEAD(value) over (order by rowInt) - Value  
from #tmp
```

LEAD(value) will return the value of the next row in respect to the given order in "over" clause.

Comment: LAG. Not LAD. It won't let me edit because you have to change 6 characters

Comment: This is the best solution. Other answers are ingenuitive, but this is efficient.

Comment: @DonkeyKong - Other answers reflect that the question is for SQL Server 2005, which does not support Analytic/Windowed Functions.

Answer (score 12):

If you really want to be sure of orders, use "Row_Number()" and compare next record of current record (take a close look at "on" clause)

```
T1.ID + 1 = T2.ID
```

You are basically joining next row with current row, without specifying "min" or doing "top".  If you have a small number of records, other solutions by "Dems" or "Quassanoi" will work fine.

```
with T2 as (
    select  ID = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by rowInt),
            rowInt, Value
    from    myTable
)
select  T1.RowInt, T1.Value, Diff = IsNull(T2.Value, 0) - T1.Value
from    (   SELECT  ID = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by rowInt), *
            FROM    myTable ) T1
        left join T2 on T1.ID + 1 = T2.ID
ORDER BY T1.ID
```

Answer (score 4):

Does SQL Server support analytic functions?

```
select   rowint,
         value,
         value - lag(value) over (order by rowint) diff
from     myTable
order by rowint
/
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'lag' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Ive given this a point because yes Denali does...although maybe sql server didnt when this answer was posted

Comment: @FairFunk I've subtracted a point because the question is tagged 2005 so Denali functionality is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.rowInt,t1.Value,t2.Value-t1.Value as diff
from (select * from myTable) as t1,
     (select * from myTable where rowInt!=1
      union all select top 1 rowInt=COUNT(*)+1,Value=0 from myTable) as t2
where t1.rowInt=t2.rowInt-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Query to Find the date difference between 2 rows of a single column

```
SELECT
Column name,
DATEDIFF(
(SELECT MAX(date) FROM table name WHERE Column name < b. Column name),
Column name) AS days_since_last
FROM table name AS b
```

Comment: This is a very old question and your answer doesn't really answer the same question posed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just make a little function for that. Toss in the two values you need to know the difference between and have it subtract the smaller from the larger value. Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NumDifference] 
    (   @p1 FLOAT,
        @p2 FLOAT )
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Diff FLOAT
    IF @p1 > @p2 SET @Diff = @p1 - @p2 ELSE SET @Diff = @p2 - @p1
    RETURN @Diff
END
```

In a query to get the difference between column a and b:

```
SELECT a, b, dbo.NumDifference(a, b) FROM YourTable
```