# MySQL - How do I to select data from a table, ordering by the difference between the values of two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In a mysql table I have, I want to select all the rows and all the columns, but by ordering them by the difference between the values of two values of the same column. Is there a way to write such an SQL query? Thank you very much!

Comment: could you expand on `difference between the values of two values of the same column`? How do you know which to compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY (ColumnA - ColumnB)
```

Comment: But the question asked for `two values of the same column`

Comment: i hope this will helps you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634568/how-to-get-difference-between-two-rows-for-a-column-field