# sql compute difference between 2 rows

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I'm looking for a methodology to compare the difference between 2 rows in the same table. From what I found here ([How to get difference between two rows for a column field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634568/how-to-get-difference-between-two-rows-for-a-column-field)) it's almost what I wanted. I have done the following code:

```
create table #tmpTest
(
    id_fund int null,
    id_ShareType int null,
    ValueDate datetime null,
    VarNAV float null,
    FundPerf float null,
)

insert into #tmpTest(id_fund, id_ShareType, ValueDate, VarNAV)
values(1,1,'20140101',100)
insert into #tmpTest(id_fund, id_ShareType, ValueDate, VarNAV) 
values(1,1,'20140102',20)

update #tmpTest
set hrc.FundPerf = (isnull(hrn.VarNAV, 0) - hrc.VarNAV)/hrc.VarNAV
from #tmpTest hrc 
left join #tmpTest hrn on hrn.ValueDate = (select min(ValueDate) from #tmpTest where ValueDate > hrc.ValueDate)
and hrc.id_fund = hrn.id_fund and hrc.id_ShareType = hrn.id_ShareType
```

My issue is that the result I'm computing starts on line 1 instead of line 2.

Hereunder the result I'm obtaining:

```
id_fund id_ShareType ValueDate           VarNAV                       FundPerf                     
------- ------------ ------------------- ------- -----------------------------
      1            1 2014-01-01 00:00:00     100                          -0.8
      1            1 2014-01-02 00:00:00      20                            -1
```

whereas I'd like it to be that way:

```
id_fund id_ShareType ValueDate           VarNAV                       FundPerf                     
------- ------------ ------------------- ------- -----------------------------
      1            1 2014-01-01 00:00:00     100                            -1
      1            1 2014-01-02 00:00:00      20                          -0.8
```

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Why can't you use `LAG` and `LEAD` functions?

Answer (score 1):

You are not restricting the minimum to the same fund and share type.

```
update #tmpTest
    set hrc.FundPerf = (isnull(hrn.VarNAV, 0) - hrc.VarNAV)/hrc.VarNAV
    from #tmpTest hrc left join
         #tmpTest hrn
         on hrn.ValueDate = (select min(ValueDate)
                             from #tmpTest tt
                             where tt.ValueDate > hrc.ValueDate and
                                   hrc.id_fund = tt.id_fund and hrc.id_ShareType = tt.id_ShareType 
                            ) and
           hrc.id_fund = hrn.id_fund and hrc.id_ShareType = hrn.id_ShareType ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update hrn
set FundPerf = (isnull(hrn.VarNAV, 0) - hrc.VarNAV)/hrc.VarNAV
from #tmpTest hrc 
left join #tmpTest hrn on hrn.ValueDate = (select min(ValueDate) from #tmpTest where ValueDate > hrc.ValueDate)
and hrc.id_fund = hrn.id_fund and hrc.id_ShareType = hrn.id_ShareType
```

Comment: Also, restrict the minimum to fund and share type as suggested by @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Indeed you're correct: I should restrict. Nevertheless, this doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: It does. If you update hrn instead of hrc, returns are aligned with dates (performance for the first day is NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieve this using by CTE (Common Table Expression)

```
create table #tmpTest
(
    id_fund int null,
    id_ShareType int null,
    ValueDate datetime null,
    VarNAV float null,
    FundPerf float null,
)

insert into #tmpTest(id_fund, id_ShareType, ValueDate, VarNAV)
values(1,1,'20140101',100)
insert into #tmpTest(id_fund, id_ShareType, ValueDate, VarNAV) 
values(1,1,'20140102',20)

;With tbl as
```

`( Select Row_Number() OVER (Order by T.ValueDate) as RowNumber,*
    From #tmpTest T
)SELECT Cur.*,(ISNULL(Cur.VarNAV,0) - ISNULL(Prv.VarNAV,0))/Prv.VarNAV as [Col Name] 
FROM tbl Cur 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl Prv ON Cur.RowNumber = Prv.RowNumber+1
ORDER BY Cur.ValueDate`

Comment: Highlighting your code and pressing Ctrl+K will format it, making it easier to read - see [how to format here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189)