# Delta of values in same table over time - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of data as below in SQL Server:

```
+-------+------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
|  ID   |       IP   |              Date       |                 NumFails |
+-------+------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
| 21365 | 172.16.2.1 | 2016-05-16 00:20:54.000 |                      200 |
| 21457 | 172.16.3.1 | 2016-05-16 00:21:05.000 |                      295 |
| 21478 | 172.16.4.1 | 2016-05-16 00:22:46.000 |                      128 |
| 24255 | 172.16.2.1 | 2016-05-16 12:22:01.000 |                      213 |
| 24318 | 172.16.3.1 | 2016-05-16 12:22:12.000 |                      297 |
| 24366 | 172.16.4.1 | 2016-05-16 12:23:52.000 |                      243 |
| 25699 | 172.16.2.1 | 2016-05-16 18:21:31.000 |                      226 |
| 25794 | 172.16.3.1 | 2016-05-16 18:21:41.000 |                      347 |
| 25811 | 172.16.4.1 | 2016-05-16 18:22:51.000 |                      270 |
| 27142 | 172.16.2.1 | 2016-05-17 00:22:45.000 |                      227 |
| 27193 | 172.16.3.1 | 2016-05-17 00:22:55.000 |                      347 |
| 27251 | 172.16.4.1 | 2016-05-17 00:23:59.000 |                      270 |
+-------+------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I have an idea of how to do this programmatically, but I'm too new to SQL to know how to do this: I want to get the delta of NumFails given a specific time period. For this, I want to be able to do a query that:

Selects IP address from time period A (<2016-05-17 01:00:00.000 and >2016-05-17 00:00:00.000) and matching IP address from time period B (<2016-05-16 01:00:00.000 and >2016-05-16 00:00:00.000) and returns IP address and the difference from period A numfails result MINUS period b numfails result.  This is done for every unique IP address in time period A (all are unique) comparing against time period B.

Any easy way to do such a thing?  I want to run the report on a daily basis, so period A will shift to today's date, and period B will be the previous day's date.  I can pre-populate that with the calling SQL, but I have no clue what to build to grab the two values and do the difference and report.

Comment: Can you post required output for sample data above.More info on getting help fast or even upvotes here:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634568/how-to-get-difference-between-two-rows-for-a-column-field

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes each IP will exist in both timeframes.

```
declare @StartPeriodA datetime
declare @EndPeriodA datetime
declare @StartPeriodB datetime
declare @EndPeriodB datetime

set @StartPeriodA = '2016-05-17 00:00:00.000'
set @EndPeriodA = '2016-05-17 01:00:00.000'
set @StartPeriodB = '2016-05-16 00:00:00.000'
set @EndPeriodB = '2016-05-16 01:00:00.000'

select a.IP, a.PeriodAFailures - b.PeriodBFailures as 'FailureDifference'
from
(
    select IP, sum(NumFails) as PeriodAFailures
    from YourTable
    where Date between @StartPeriodA and @EndPeriodA
    group by IP
) a
inner join 
(
    select IP, sum(NumFails) as PeriodBFailures
    from YourTable
    where Date between @StartPeriodB and @EndPeriodB
    group by IP
) b on a.IP = b.IP
```

You can manipulate the dates as needed.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much.  I have a slightly better understanding now of how SQL actually can be used to grab and manipulate the values.