# How do I get the difference from the rows in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

so I have this query:

```
select  sum( case when gender = 'Male'
        then 1 else 0 end )    as male 
from tbl_person
```

it will result to something like this:

```
+------+
| male |
+------+
|    2 |
|    5 |
|   10 |
+------+
```

What I want is to have a column beside it that will show the difference of each row, something like this:

```
+------+-----+
| male | gap |
+------+-----+
|    2 |     |
|    5 |   3 |
|   10 |   5 |
+------+-----+
```

I tried some answers like here [How to get difference between two rows for a column field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634568/how-to-get-difference-between-two-rows-for-a-column-field)
But they don't seem to work. I think its because the column is a result of a Sum().

Comment: Your current query should result only one row. How you got three rows in result did you forgot to add `group by`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`LAG`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) window function

```
SELECT Male,
       COALESCE(Male - Lag(male)OVER(ORDER BY male), 0) AS gap
FROM   (SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN gender = 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS male
        FROM   tbl_person) A
```

Comment: Male is not a Column, Gender is a column. So have u forgot using Case Statement to filter out?

Comment: I tried that but it only produce an error: column "male" does not exist.