# Subtract two dates with matching field, and another specific field value in SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the time difference between two events represented as rows in the same table. Among others, the row has the following fields:

```
JobNum
EventDate
Event
```

The `Event` field is used to see if the event is the start or finish for that Job.

I need to get the time differences between the `EventDate` field where `JobNum` is the same. Because there can be multiple events for a single `JobNum`, I also need to specify that `JobNum` is the same and to only subtract the row where `EventDate= 'Starting'` from the row with `EventDate = 'Finished'`(There will always only be one `Starting` and one `Finished` event per `JobNum`).

The following is as far as i have gotten but its not working:

```
Select a.[AutoNumber], DATEDIFF(SECOND, (SELECT m.EventDate 
                                               FROM [myTable] m 
                                               WHERE m.Event = 'Starting' and a.JobNum= m.JobNum),
                                        (SELECT m.EventDate 
                                                FROM myTable m
                                                WHERE m.Event = 'Finished' and a.JobNum= m.JobNum)
       ) 
       From myTable a
```

It partially runs, but then gives the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I also took a look at this question but couldn't figure out how to modify the code to work for my situation. [How to get difference between two rows for a column field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634568/how-to-get-difference-between-two-rows-for-a-column-field)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it confirm only one single record of `Starting` and `Finished` per JobNum ? Looks like your data doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, here's one option using `conditional aggregation`:

```
Select [AutoNumber], 
       datediff(second, 
                max(case when event = 'starting' then EventDate end),
                max(case when event = 'Finished' then EventDate end)
       )
From myTable a 
Group By [AutoNumber]
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Now i need to learn about conditional aggregation. :)