# Count a result for 2 rows one under other

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

How can I add another column where will be the difference between 2nd and 3rd row, than the 3rd and the 4th and so on. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, use formatted text instead of images.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634568/how-to-get-difference-between-two-rows-for-a-column-field

Answer (score 2):

Use `lag()`:

```
select d.*,
       (department_id - lag(department_id) over (order by department_id)) as diff
from departments d;
```

Comment: Thanks  very much :D