# SQL query to get number of days between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL where one column contains lots of IDS some of which are duplicate, a second column with lots of dates all different

I want to create a table where i have unique list of IDS down the left hand side of the table, a column called number of days and then in the table the number of days between the last date and the second to last date that are in the table.

Comment: Can you provide a table structure and perhaps some sample data? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It would be great if you could post your table data along with the desired output. Visual representation goes a long way to help figure out the problem

Comment: Learn how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried following this example so far but i havent been able to work out how to find the difference between the dates, and then on top of that i havent been able to work out how to do this for each ID. I will post a table in a mo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634568/how-to-get-difference-between-two-rows-for-a-column-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I take the MAX(DateCol) that is less than the subqueried MAX(DateCol) with the same ID- this is used in the DateDiff.

```
SELECT dT.ID
      ,(SELECT MAX(DateCol)              
          FROM @YourTable Y
         WHERE Y.DateCol < dT.MaxDateCol --Date less than MAX
           AND Y.ID = dT.ID
       ) AS [Date less than MAX]   --added by request
      ,dT.MaxDateCol AS [Max Date] --added by request
      ,DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT MAX(DateCol)              
                        FROM @YourTable Y
                       WHERE Y.DateCol < dT.MaxDateCol --Date less than MAX
                         AND Y.ID = dT.ID
                     ) 
                   , dT.MaxDateCol
               ) AS [Days Difference] --datediff between max and date less than MAX
  FROM (    
        SELECT ID
              ,MAX([DateCol]) [MaxDateCol] --MAX, removes duplicate ID's.
          FROM @YourTable
        GROUP BY ID
       ) AS dT
```

Comment: @ Zorkolot thank you for the help on this, understanding derived tables is a little above me. What if i wanted to display the 2 dates which the differences are being calculated from how would i display each of these in two separate columns? I have tried playing around with the code above but not to much luck :(

Comment: See the above changes. I've annotated the lines with `--added by request`. 
 Notice the datediff takes these 2 dates as written.

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad I could help you!

Comment: @ Zorkolot i do have a question WHERE DateReading < dT.MaxDateCol --Date less than MAX, how does SQL no its not every date before the max date and just the one previous?

Comment: The bottom subquery `(...) AS dT`  executes first.  Returned from this is the [MaxDateCol] and ID.  I reference this using the "dT" alias in the receiving query: `dT.ID, dT.MaxDateCol` (see the reference? dT... the value comes from the bottom subquery).  Notice I do yet another subquery- `SELECT MAX(DateCol) FROM YourTable Y WHERE Y.DateCol < dt.MaxDateCol`.   The less than sign (<) is the important part.  I query the original table for the MAX date less than dT.MaxDateCol- that would be 2nd highest.

Comment: @ Zorkolot oh yes i see the bottom sub query where the max is obtained first. If i had a 1000 different readings less than the max date the < would only bring the date less than this, out of interest what would i then do if i wanted 2 dates previous to the maximum? No need to make this as amendment to the completed solution above its just out of curiosity

Comment: I would probably approach it with a different algorithm.  It would use a partition-by to add a rownumber.  The rownumber would be in the order of Xth-highest.  I don't have access to SQL Server so I can't test this atm and am writing off the top of my head... but it would be similar to:  'SELECT ID 
      ,DateCol 
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DateCol DESC) AS RowNum 
  FROM @YourTable 
ORDER BY ID ASC 
       , DateCol DESC'      - you could then subquery this to see where rownumber = 3, for example.

Comment: @ Zorkolot it was purely out of curiosity so i dont require you to do anything. This has really benefited me so thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Using Row_Number() in concert with a conditional aggregation.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[DateCol] date)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'2017-05-01')
,(1,'2017-05-05')
,(1,'2017-05-10')  -- 2nd 
,(1,'2017-05-31')  -- Lst  21 days
,(2,'2017-05-01')
,(2,'2017-06-05')
,(2,'2017-06-10')  -- 2nd
,(2,'2017-07-31')  -- Lst 51 days

Select ID
      ,Days = DateDiff(DAY,max(case when RN=2 then DateCol end),max(case when RN=1 then DateCol end))
 From (
        Select *
              ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order by DateCol Desc) 
         from @YourTable
      ) A 
 Group By ID
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Days
1   21
2   51
```

Comment: I'm trying to interpret OP's request as well. _"...the number of days between the last date and the second to last date that are in the table."_  For your example ID1 should be 21 days?

Comment: I have tried applying it to the table as John's example of the table is correct but i am sttruggling here is my query SELECT TOP 100000 [YIT_ID]
     
  ,Days = DateDiff(DAY,min(Reading_Date),max(case when RN=2 then Reading_Date end))   
   
   
   from [YIT].[dbo].[YIT_Readings]
  

    Select *
              ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order by DateCol Desc) 
         from [YIT].[dbo].[YIT_Readings]
      ) A 
 --Group By ID

Comment: @MrAssistance See updated answer,  Zorkolot pointed out that I missed last and 2nd last.