# Calculate time difference between rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I hope someone can help. I have a table that looks like the following.

```
ModifyDate| ModifiedBy | TaskID |
2018-02-05| Bob        | 55444  |
2018-02-06| Lily       | 55444  |
2018-02-08| Sarah      | 55444  |
```

For each row I need to calculate the time difference in days between `Modifydate` for each `TaskID`.

For example my output should look like the below:

```
ModifyDate| ModifiedBy | TaskID | Time
2018-02-05| Bob        | 55444  |  1
2018-02-06| Lily       | 55444  |  2
2018-02-08| Sarah      | 55444  | NULL
```

There is a NULL on Sarah as she was the last person to modify the Task.

Does this make sense? Hopefully someone can help

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634568/how-to-get-difference-between-two-rows-for-a-column-field

Comment: @ErayBalkanli that's not applicable to SQL Server 2012. You no longer need to JOIN to get the previous row

Comment: Yea you are right

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT ModifyDate, ModifiedBy, TaskID,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, ModifyDate,
                     LEAD(ModifyDate) OVER (PARTITION BY TaskID  
                                            ORDER BY ModifyDate))
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8b7ec/1)