# SQL Subtracting Cost by Rows

Tags: sql, date, select, row, ranking

I have a dataset

```
--City        Brand     Cost       Date
--Nashville   A         $100       11/14/2023
--Nashville   A         $125       11/15/2023
```

I would like to see

```
--City        Brand     Difference  Latest Date
--Nashville   A         $25         11/15/2023
```

Thanks in advance!!

With `RankedCombination`

Partion over
were row num <= 1

etc

Comment: Please specify database you use

Comment: What if there were 3rd row containing e.g. Nashville, A, $200, 11/16/2023? Or only one row? Or 100 rows per [City, Brand] combination?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get difference between two rows for a column field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634568/how-to-get-difference-between-two-rows-for-a-column-field)

Comment: So this would be latest date over the second to latest date.  If there was a 100 rows, it would take todays date minus yesterdays date, or todays date minus three days ago which ever one is more recent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sql gives desired result in Oracle:

```
select city,brand,difference,datecol 
from (select rownum as r,city,brand,
      cost - lead(cost) over (order by datecol desc) as difference, 
      datecol 
      from t1 order by datecol desc)
where r=1;
```

Comment: I am getting the error "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline function, derived tables, subqueries and common table expressions

select city, brand, difference, newdate
from (select row_num as r, city, brand,
cost 0 lead(cost) over (order by newdate desc) as difference, newdate
where #T_temp order by newdate) where r=1