# which query is more preferable and why

Tags: sql

i am trying to teach myself SQL and of course I would like to follow best practices.

I have created two querys to find the latest record :

```
select * from AppSurvey where 
DateLastUsed >= ( SELECT MAX(DateLastUsed) FROM AppSurvey)
```

and

```
select top 1 * from AppSurvey order by DateLastUsed desc
```

is one of these methods more efficent than the other or does it really matter

Comment: These are actually two different queries, if DateLastUsed isn't unique. So, apples to oranges. The top one can select many surveys while the bottom one will only sample one.

Comment: The first query could return more than 1 record, so they actually don't do the same thing.   In MS-SQL, the second query is more efficent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similiar post on this site to what you are trying to get at.

[For autoincrement fields: MAX(ID) vs TOP 1 ID ORDER BY ID DESC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590079/for-autoincrement-fields-maxid-vs-top-1-id-order-by-id-desc)

The preferred answer seems to be: "In theory, they will use same plans and run almost same time"

Answer (score 1):

The first one could get more than one row, if your DateLastUsed column isn't unique.