# Last id value in a table. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to know the last `nth` id field of a table, without scanning it completely? (just go to the end of table and get id value)

```
table
id   fieldvalue
1    2323
2    4645
3    556
...  ...
100000000  1232
```

So for example here `n = 100000000` 100 Million

**--------------EDIT-----**
So which one of the queries proposed would be more efficient?

Comment: if all you want is the id number and not the whole record, mine is the quickest - which is why i posted it as it answered the question as posed.  Now if you want the WHOLE record, it would be what michael suggested.  And on a sidenote: if it is the id and primary key, it should already be indexed by default (I believe)

Comment: Tough to say, an answer on this post seems to indicate that IDENT_CURRENT is the fastest, but I'm having a hard time confirming that anywhere else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590079/for-autoincrement-fields-maxid-vs-top-1-id-order-by-id-desc.  IDENT_CURRENT works over any session and any scope, so it may be preferable if there is alot of activity on this table.

Comment: Just for fun, I ran both methods against a test DB I have while running SQL Profiler.  Both are really fast, but IDENT_CURRENT is showing 0's for CPU/Reads/Duration while MAX(ID) does cause a slight number of reads.  I think IDENT_CURRENT is faster, but chances are either will work fine as far as performance is concerned.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM <tablename>
```

Comment: Yeah sometimes the answer really is as simple as you think.. other times it can be so obscure though!

Comment: Yes, thaks for the immediate answer

Comment: Bear in mind that this makes the assumption that the `id` value is a monotonically increasing value (the OP does not say anything about this being an `identity` column, though by all appearances it is).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming ID is the IDENTITY for the table, you could use `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('TABLE NAME')`.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) for more info.

**One thing to note about this approach:** If you have INSERTs that fail but increment the IDENTITY counter, then you will get back a result that is higher than the result returned by `SELECT MAX(id) FROM <tablename>`

Comment: Actually, it would have to be an `INT IDENTITY` field - not a primary key (that's irrelevant)

Comment: One thing to note about this approach, if you have INSERTs that fail but increment the IDENTITY counter, then you will get back a result that is higher than the result returned by SELECT MAX(id) FROM <tablename>.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use system tables to get all last values from all identity columns in system:

```
select
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) + '.' + name as col_name
    , last_value 
from 
    sys.identity_columns 
order by last_value desc
```

Answer (score 1):

In case when `table1` rows are inserted first, and then rows to `table2` which depend on ids from the `table1`, you can use `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (`some_id`, `some_value`)
VALUES ((SELECT some_id
        FROM `table1`
        WHERE `other_key_1` = 'xxx'
            AND `other_key_2` = 'yyy'),
        'some value abc abc 123 123 ...');
```

Of course, this can work only if there are other identifiers that can uniquely identify rows from `table1`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to access the table in DESCENDING order by ID.

Then you would select the TOP N records.

At this point, you want the last record of the set which hopefully is obvious. Assuming that the id field is indexed, this would at most retrieve the last N records of the table and most likely would end up being optimized into a single record fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Select Ident_Current('Your Table Name') gives the last Id of your table.