# Convert this SQL Query to NHibernate Criteria Queries

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Need to convert this sql query to nhibernate criterion language... How can I do this?

```
 select 
     * 
 from Feeds where Id = 
 (select MAX(Id) from Feeds where DataId = [VARIABLE PARAMETER])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Feed feed = _session.CreateCriteria<Feed>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("DataId", "[VARIABLE PARAMETER]"))
    .AddOrder(new Order("_id", false))
    .SetMaxResults(1)
    .List<Feed>()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

That will result in something like:

```
select TOP 1 * from Feeds where DataId = ??? Order By Id desc
```

There should be no [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590079/625332) from performance point of view.